# You must finish editing the current row gridview validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I am new to the wonderful world of asp.net gridviews. As of now, my gridview would have several rows each with a edit and update button. When I click edit, the editable cells turn into textboxes and can be successfully updated. However, if I am in edit mode in one row, and I click an update button in another row, an error will fire.

So my question is, how could I validate that the current row finished editing? Ive been searching google and I understand how to make field templates, assign a control, and can validate a certain cell. But I am not sure of a way to force someone to finish editing before causing that error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you provide an update button when the row is not in edit mode?

Comment: That is a good question. Should I make the update buttons all invis until I click edit?

Comment: You could set [`AutoGenerateEditButton `](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateeditbutton.aspx) to `true`. Then an update + cancel button are shown when edit was clicked.

Comment: wow. I feel like a complete noob. Make an answer for points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>From comments:</sub>

Why do you provide an update button when the row is not in edit mode?

You could set [`AutoGenerateEditButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogenerateeditbutton.aspx) to `true`. Then update + cancel buttons are shown when edit was clicked.